# javascript html5 canvas: selection rectangles, want to draw one but drawing multiple

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm creating a UI for myself in which I define boxes on which to perform OCR. That's not the important part. We are considering the frontend. For the UI, the idea is to draw a rectangle using the mouse (mousedown, mousemove, mouseup). But my script draws multiple rectangles instead of just one. Here is an image of the problem.

[image: multiple rectangles]

I want to draw only one rectangle for each selection rectangle. How can I do this? Here is my selection code.

```
        var ctx = Data.ctx_items[index];

        //get box
        Data.canvas_items[index].addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
            Data.x1 = e.offsetX;
            Data.y1 = e.offsetY;
            Data.is_drawing = true;
        })

        Data.canvas_items[index].addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){

            if(Data.is_drawing){
                Data.x2 = e.offsetX - Data.x1;
                Data.y2 = e.offsetY - Data.y1;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.rect(Data.x1, Data.y1, Data.x2, Data.y2);
                ctx.stroke();
            }
            
        })

        Data.canvas_items[index].addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
            Data.is_drawing = false;
        })
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you need to clear previous paths

Comment: the rectangles are drawn on top of a canvas element (pdf) that is not to be altered. @appleapple . Clearing the rectangles will clear part of the pdf, and I don't want that.

Comment: then either you don't draw on that canvas, or you redraw that part of PDF.